# Filling up chunk to full - reading file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, readfile, chunks

I am reading file in standard way in python. I mean like this :

```
 with open("path_to_my_file", "rb") as fh:
        chunk = fh.read(5120)
```

But when I read file for example 22000byte size it gives me 5 chunks

1 - 5120

2 - 5120

3 - 5120

4 - 5120

5 - 1520

There is an option to fill up to full last chunk by Nulls on 1521-5120 indexes ??

Answer (score 1):

I thing the simplest way is to do something like this :

```
    padded_chunk = ( chunk + '\0'*5120 ) [:5120]
```

Now `padded_chunk` is end-padded with nulls.

Comment: When I add your line it gives me error `TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: Oops, sorry ! I'm using python 2.7... With python 3.x, reading a binary file gives a `bytearray`.

Try this : `padded_chunk = ( chunk + bytearray( '\0'*5120 )) [:5120]`

Comment: Now :`TypeErrpr : string argument without an encoding` :D

Comment: Sorry I don't have python 3 on my computer, so I can't test it...
But here is a more simple way, since `bytearray` allow to do that : `padded_chunk = ( chunk + bytearray( 5120-len( chunk )))`
   (no more string/unicode!)

Comment: So what should I use ? I'm little confused

Comment: Well, the last one : `padded_chunk = chunk + bytearray( 5120-len( chunk ))`

Comment: ok it works with `bytes( 5120-len( chunk ))` not bytearray. But it will fill end with nulls ?

Comment: Explanation about `bytes` here : (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=open#func-bytes) : If the parameter is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.